# Run Raspberry Pi script from Windows PC using Ethernet

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

As the title says, I want to run a script on the Raspberry Pi from my Windows PC. The connection between PC and Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian OS) should be done using an Ethernet cable. The Rasperry Pi cannot be operated permanently in the network. Is it correct that then a SSH connection is out of the question?
For background: the Raspberry Pi is connected to a camera and a stepper motor. Depending on the position of the object to be photographed, the stepper motor is moved and then a photo is taken. This photo is then to be sent back to the PC via the network cable. The script on the Raspberry Pi (rotation stepper motor and image capture) is implemented with Python and fully functional. Is it generally possible to run the Pi script using the Ethernet cable and transfer the generated images back?
Using a Windows QT GUI I want to start this script and display the images later.
Is this possible or can someone suggest a simpler way? Maybe someone already had a similar problem and would help me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"cannot be operated permanently in the network"* please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extra Ethernet NIC on your computer, you can directly connect your PC and Raspberry PI (on relatively newer hardware) or if that doesn't work, you can use a crossover Ethernet cable to connect your PC to the PI. Then configure an ssh server on the PI and enable Avahi and dhcpd and execute your script via that using MSYS ssh or Putty (`ssh pi@hostname.local`). Don't forget to change your hostname.

Bonus tip: you can also send your data (images) back over the same connection.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your help. I will give it a try. I still have one question. Is it then also possible to run this script on the Pi using a Windows exe? Do you have me maybe a suitable example for this? I can't find one. Also, I'm still not clear then how to send back the generated images from my existing Python script.

Comment: What language is the script in? You can set up a simple server (http / ftp) on Windows to accept images sent from the PI.

Comment: The language will also be Python.

Comment: @Michael, the Python script can run as is on the Raspberry Pi. I am not sure what exactly you meant by "Do you have me maybe a suitable example for this?"